# Meteor React populate form with existing data

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I'm learning how to use meteor with react so forgive the basic question.

I want to create a form that populates when the page loads if the data has already been submitted. I've been trying to use `getInitialState` however I'm not getting anywhere. Some help would be really appreciated.

Path: `MyResolutions.jsx`

```
export default class MyResolutions extends Component {

    getInitialState() {
        return {
            resolution: Resolutions.find().fetch(),
            timeToComplete: Resolutions.find().fetch(),
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.addResolutions.bind(this)}>
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    ref="resolution"
                    placeholder="Resolution title"
                    value={this.state.resolution} />
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    ref="timeToComplete"
                    placeholder="Time To Complete"
                    value={this.state.timeToComplete} />

                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the shape of your data coming from your initial state:

```
getInitialState() {
    return {
        resolution: Resolutions.find().fetch(),
        timeToComplete: Resolutions.find().fetch(),
    };
}
```

Assuming that `this.state.resolution` returns something like:

```
{
   value: 'some string'
}
```

You would actually have to do something like `this.state.resolution.value` . So maybe try `console.log(this.state.resolution)` to get the shape of your data and then use dot notation to display the keys you need.

Comment: Ok, I think I need to go back a step because I'm not following this at all. Sorry. Could you point me in the direction of a good tut that runs through editing an excisiting form.

Comment: Your problem is not editing an existing form, your problem is that you're not understanding what `this.state.resolution` returns. When you find a meteor collection it will return an object. So when you send `this.state.resolution` into the value of your input, it's trying to send a javascript object which cannot be rendered by React. You need to access one of the keys of the object.